# How to override repositioning of callout view in Mapbox when panning?

Tags: ios, mapbox

(Re: Mapbox for Swift) I implemented a custom callout view using the example on the Mapbox website (https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/custom-callout/). When the annotation is near the edge of the screen, the **default** callout view will adjust its x-value position accordingly so that the callout will fit entirely within view. One way that this feature can be replicated in the **custom** callout view is by applying an adjustment (if needed) when setting the frame of `self` (the callout view itself):

```
self.frame = CGRect(x: frameOriginX + adjustmentX, y: frameOriginY, width: frameWidth, height: frameHeight)
```

In the present callout delegate method:

```
func presentCallout(from rect: CGRect, in view: UIView, constrainedTo constrainedView: UIView, animated: Bool)
```

However, the *custom* callout, when doing this, will revert its position back to center above `rect` (the annotation view) when the user begins panning (or even touches the map or another annotation). In the *default* callout view, however, when the user pans the map, the adjustment applied to the callout view remains.

Therefore, how do you properly adjust the custom callout view's x-value position and preserve it as the user pans the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callout view is redrawn when the user pans the map. You will have to override the `draw` function of your custom callout to adjust the x position every time it is redrawn.